# Dual booting ubuntu 14.04 windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I installed ubuntu together with windows 10 in a PC originally running windows 10. In the UEFI firmware I disabled the secure booting and the fast booting and put in the order of booting, ubuntu first.

The grub booting of ubuntu shows the choice to boot with ubuntu or with the windows boot manager. So far, the dual booting seems to work well.

But if I boot Windows from the window booting manager in the menu of booting, when restarting the PC again the booting don't go to that menu and automatically open windows. **Checking the UEFI firmware the secure booting and fast booting are kept disabled, but the order of booting move windows back to the first position. (?)**.

Notice that the windows manager don't remove the grub booting manager, as if I change the order of booting in the firmware, putting again ubuntu first is the grub manager that takes control and I am able to open ubuntu again. **What the booting from the windows manager do is to change the order  of booting in the firmware, placing windows first, and not removing grub.**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

this is generally provided when you run boot-repair.

Best bet for you will be within Windows try to restart with Shift button pressed and follow the options to boot into Ubuntu.
Once you are in Ubuntu try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: Boot Repair is unlikely to do any good. Because it's a pretty heavy-handed repair tool, there's a (small) chance that it will make matters worse, so I recommend against using it. That said, your first suggestion (of using `bcdedit` in Windows) is good. That tool often overcomes this specific problem.

Comment: Yes, the command** bcdedit** in a command prompt of windows works fine. Now, after starting from the windows booting manager if I restart the computer it shows the menu with the options ubuntu or windows manager and not automatically opening windows as before.